# UML diagrams from ASP.net Application design specs

Tags: c#, asp.net, uml, mvp

I work in a mid size company as a intermediate developer and work on developing web projects.  I got a situtation where i need to develop UML out of the design specs and this will be the main technical specification (High level though and will get futher changed in process of acutal development).

Can someone provide guidlines on how to start on this (or) there any good samples online ?

Planning to use Visio for UML, how good is this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/) a lot for creating specifications. Sparx systems is the company that sells it for relatively cheap. Go over the demos and see if you like it. It is a neat tool for $135.

Answer (score 0):

My limited experience with Visio and UML has been very unpleasant, but that was a few years back, so they might have improved since. I found the [Visual Paradigm](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/vpuml/) tool reasonably usable to produce UML diagrams - and they have a free community edition, with a watermark, so you can try it out and see if you like it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NClass (Since you are using .NET and may be C# also) also for UML design, this will help you in creating code also according to the UML created by you in NClass.

Comment: From what I could see, NClass supports only class diagrams - that seems a bit limited!

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your environment of course. Microsoft Visio has some decent UML diagramming tools. Eclipse has some tools available (visual paradigm is one). When it comes down to it, I prefer a whiteboard and/or paper and a pencil.